# open eclipse project in android studio - google_play_services

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I am sorry if this a repetition
but i have a project and need to open in android studio.

but as we all know project.property file makes trouble.
i can remove the line there and open it , then when the project open it generates the errors  so it is not the best way

can some one give me the example of a project.property path so i can get the idea because if i add the google_play_services lib in the correct way it should work right?

need guidance from developers who met this issue

here my project.property file line

## Project target.

target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../../../../../WORK/Library/google-play-services_lib

any example please

Comment: did you added dependency of google play service

Comment: export your project as gradle build from eclipse and import it in AS

Comment: yes i did it didn't fix the issue i have google play service in my extras

Comment: when i add 
android.library.reference.1= MY PATH FOR GPS LIb why does not it work